# Uploading Video using node-js vimeo-api

Tags: node.js, vimeo-api

I am trying to setup a single user application in Node.js that will upload videos to my application using vimeo-api ( https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js )

I am following the guide ( https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload ), but it doesn't seem to work.

I have the following code:

```
    var Vimeo = require('vimeo-api').Vimeo;
    var lib = new Vimeo(MY_CLIENT_ID, MY_CLIENT_SECRET);
    lib.access_token = "<OAUTH_TOKEN>";
```

---

I tried:

```
    lib.request({path: "/me", method: "GET"}, function (error, body, status_code, headers) {console.log(body);})
```

Received:

```
    {
      uri: '/users/26512824',
      name: 'Dipankar',
      link: 'https://vimeo.com/user26512824',
      ...
      account: 'basic',
      pictures: ... ,
      websites: [],
      stats: {},
      metadata: ... ,
      content_filter: [ 'language', 'drugs', 'violence', 'nudity', 'safe', 'unrated' ]
    }
```

---

When I tried following to get upload ticket:

```
    lib.request({path: "/me/videos", method: "POST"}, function (error, body, status_code, headers) {console.log(body);})
```

I get:

```
    null
```

---

Further, I tried via cURL just to verify the steps

```
    curl --data "" -H "Authorization: bearer <OAUTH_TOKEN>" https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos
```

And the response is:

```
    {
      "error": "The app is not allowed to perform that action. [Missing permission to upload to owner]."
    }
```

---

I guess I have missed something. I also get the following message in the apps page which might be relevant:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check the status code any time you get a null body. That will clue you in to more information.

I assume you are receiving a 401 status code, which means you do not have the proper authentication to upload a video with this app.

Once you have been granted upload access, check out https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js/blob/master/lib/vimeo.js#L288

The node library already supports upload, it's just undocumented because there haven't been thorough tests on large file sizes. The first parameter is the full path to the video file, and the second parameter is a callback.

This callback is called once the upload is complete and will have a "Location" header containing the URI of the final video resource.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with the code.
I just received an email from Vimeo regarding Upload Access not being granted for not meeting the requirements. I guess the failure resulted from that.

I am trying to setup app with proper details and try the uploads again when I am granted the upload access.

Comment: Dashron, I didn't get the upload access with my account at Vimeo due to some reasons.
I have no visible way to confirm your answer. Sorry for not marking it as correct so far.

Comment: No worries, if you disagree with the reasons your upload access was denied (or weren't properly informed) you can reach out to vimeo at https://vimeo.com/help/contact

Comment: @Dashron I need to upload video using only javascript because I am working on business catalyst where I do not have server side coding option. I am wondering if your proposed solution work for me? 

Please note: I never worked with nodejs. I have viewed some tutorials of nodjs and find out its some sort of server side javascript library.

Comment: Any time secret information is involved, such as secret keys, or authentication tokens, I don't recommend a purely client side tool. There's always the chance your authentication tokens are leaked and someone can upload videos to your account.